# Julia loop over dataframe columns

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to convert dataframe columns from string to int to boolean using a loop. I have confirmed that n does correctly catch the df column names but am unable to reference them in the convert statement.

```
for n in (names(df))
    df[!,:n] = convert.(Bool, (parse.(Int,df[!,:n])))
end
```

The error I get is:

*ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: column name :n not found in the data frame*

Comment: The problem is `:n` is a symbol and is not referring to `n` in your loop `for n in ...`, to refer to `n` use `n` not `:n`, i.e. the second line should be `df[!,n] = convert.(Bool, (parse.(Int,df[!,n])))`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `:` before the column names, and `parse` can parse a string as a Bool too.

```
transform!(df, names(df) .=> ByRow(x->parse(Bool, x)), renamecols = false)
```

Comment: or `mapcols(x -> parse.(Bool, x), df)`,